# Wordpress - Custom order on CPT and Taxonomy pages

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am creating a function to order a specific custom post type (ex : produit). It works well on the CPT archive page but it doesn't work on the custom taxonomy pages (ex: categories) :

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

// do not modify queries in the admin
if( is_admin() ) {

    return $query;

}

// only modify queries for 'produit' post type
if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && $query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'produit') {

    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');   
    $query->set('meta_key', 'irank');    
    $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 

}

// return
return $query;

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

How can I append my code so the custom order applies also to my custom taxonomy pages ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the `is_tax()` function to check if it's the taxonomy archive you want to alter the sort order on. So something like this...

```
if ( $query->is_tax( 'produit-category' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {

    $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');   
    $query->set('meta_key', 'irank');    
    $query->set('order', 'DESC'); 
}
```